# How is CLI commands used in ember addon for dummy app?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to build an ember addon and am using the dummy app as demo project.

When trying to create model using ember-cli, the code is generated inside the ember app folder instead of the dummy app (tests/dummy/app).

```
ember generate model ticket name:string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target your dummy app in your ember-cli generate commands using the `--dummy` flag.

In your example, `$ ember generate model ticket name:string --dummy` would generate the `tests/dummy/app/models/ticket.js` file.

You can run `$ ember` in your project to print the available options for each command.

Comment: Working great ! Thanks a lot.